# Spring Batch FlatFileItemReader get iput line

Tags: java, spring-batch

Am getting below Exception if my flat file has incorrect number of tokens.

```
2017-05-25 11:58:31,337 ERROR org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader (FlatFileItemReader.java:199)- Parsing error at line: 7 in resource=file [C:\flatfiles\temp\input.JOCCH], input=[710,01,67000,C,20170328,20170327,TRAN1,HF1,,,,]
org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 11 actual 12
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer.tokenize(PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.mapLine(PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:87)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:106)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:242)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:348)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.access$100(FlowJob.java:43)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob$JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If i caught incorrectnumberoftokens exception i want to print custom error log with filename, line number and line causing exception.

Help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Spring Batch documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip), just set it as a skippable exception and register a `SkipListener` ([also well documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#skipListener)).

**Example Context Configuration:**

```
<step id="step1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="flatFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10" skip-limit="10">
            <skippable-exception-classes>
                <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException"/>
            </skippable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="loggingSkipListener" />
        </listeners>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="loggingSkipListener" class="com.example.MyLoggingSkipListener" />
```

**`SkipListener` interface to implement:**

```
public interface SkipListener<T,S> extends StepListener {

    void onSkipInRead(Throwable t);
    void onSkipInProcess(T item, Throwable t);
    void onSkipInWrite(S item, Throwable t);

}
```